# How to set function region for angularfire 7.3.0

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I'm having trouble setting the functions-region with angularfire 7.3.0.

I'm importing the modules using v7 modular, and I can't seem to find good instructions on how to change the functions region when using this method.

What I've tried:

Using `compat`:

```
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule, REGION } from '@angular/fire/functions';
...
    providers: [
    ...
      { provide: REGION, useValue: 'europe-west1' }
    ]
```

Using `getFunctions`:

```
provideFunctions(() => getFunctions(getApp(), 'europe-west1'));
```

Both seem to fail to set the region, although the last method is described as the correct one.

When checking the FunctionsInstances I get this:
[FunctionsInstances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFMFl.png)

This seems to indicate that the region is set correctly, but when calling a function I get an error saying that `https://us-central1-APPNAME.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTIONNAME` is not available, as it clearly tries to call a function from `us-central1`.

Have anybody dealt with this problem, have a fix/workaround or some insight as to why this happens?

Comment: Actually worked!

Using: provideFunctions(() => getFunctions(getApp(), 'europe-west1'));

Dunno if that's because I'm using onCall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems like you have to provide the instance in FunctionsInstance manually.

When defining the functions, do as such:

```
import { Functions, httpsCallable, FunctionsInstances } from '@angular/fire/functions'
...
// Inject Functions, FunctionsInstances
...
const functionsInstance = this.functionsInstances[0];
someFunction = httpsCallable(functionsInstance, 'someFunction');
```

By using a function-instance from the `FunctionsInstance` instead of `getFunctions()`, the call is made using the correct function-instance, and therefore the correct region.